# Can ASP.NET MVC be applied to web services?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

I'm planning architecture for a web-based application using web services.  It has been recommended that I look into using the ASP.NET MVC Framework.  All of the information I'm finding on the MVC discusses its use with web pages, but I have found nothing regarding web services.  Can the MVC be used for web services? and if so, where might I find resources to support my research effort?

Comment: I think this question needs to be clarified.  Are you asking how to consume a web service in MVC or how to deliver one using MVC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC can be used to [create REST web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573363/using-asp-net-mvc-for-rest-based-endpoint).  For SOAP, you should stick to standard Web Services.

Answer (score 2):

MVC is a UI design pattern. It is not a natural fit to web services.

Answer (score 0):

In order to dispaly data, You could use the mvc built in "JsonResults" to return all kind of entitles or collections in json format, I find it very practice.
If you need some more options I recommend you to use WCF instead of Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether you're building a web application that has a web service component, or just a web service. Web services, strictly speaking, don't have user interfaces, so the MVC model wouldn't directly apply. But there's really no substitute for thinking through what you're trying to do in a straightforward way. Architecture patterns can help, but they're only guides. It sounds like you're still feeling your way around, so don't think too much about these sorts of patterns at this stage: figure out what needs to be done and find out what technologies would be best suited to do it with. The overall architecture will emerge eventually.